# How to extract value before "/" in the given output

Tags: linux, shell

Command :

```
netstat -anp | grep -i 8009 | awk '{print $7;}'
```

Output :

```
9345/java
```

Desired Output:

```
9345
```

I want to extract only the process ID i.e. 9345.
What else i can add in my command to get desired output ??

Comment: As a general rule, if you find yourself using `grep | awk | other commands`, this can generally be merged down into one `awk`. If you show us the output of the first pipe, we can help you simplify this code.

Comment: If I remove p from -anp then I won't get the process name and process ID, where as I want to extract only the process ID which is running on the given port.

Comment: What is 8009? A port number? What happens if 8009 is the process id of some other process? Maybe you should grep for :8009. I think port numbers are always prefixed with a :

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `cut`!

```
echo "9345/java" | cut -d '/' -f 1
#Output: 9345
```

Put it all together:

```
netstat -anp | grep -i 8009 | awk '{print $7;}' | cut -d '/' -f 1
```

Comment: netstat -anp | grep -i 8009 | awk '{print $7;}' | cut -d '/' -f1

this works completely, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` with a defined delimiter-

```
netstat -anp | grep -i 8009 | awk '{print $7;}' | awk -F/ '{print $1}'
```

Or to clean it up a bit,

```
netstat -anp | awk '/8009/ {print $7;}' | awk -F/ '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do another grep

```
netstat -anp | grep -i 8009 | awk '{print $7;}' | grep --regexp="\d+[^\/]"
```

Regex explanation:

`\d+` Matches one or more numerals
`[^\/]` Exclude the character '/'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub` and provide a regex that replace every non-digit character with the empty string, resulting in only-numbers output. Modify your code:

```
netstat -anp | grep -i 8009 | awk '{sub("[^0-9]+", ""); print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

why to use both `awk` and `grep` together in one command ?

Use just `awk` :

```
netstat -anp |awk -v port="40759" '$0 ~ port {split($7,a,"/");print a[1]}'
25873
```

Or use just `grep` :

```
netstat -anp  |grep -oP '31805\s+\K.*(?=/)'
```